# XSLT Adding the price of books after an IF Statement

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt, foreach

Not really sure how to do this as the 'sum()' function is adding all the values in the XML page rather than the ones selected by the 'if' statement.

Here is the XML:

```
<book>
    <title type="non-fiction">Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone</title>
    <author>J.K Rowling</author>
    <publisher>Bloomsbury</publisher>
    <year>1997</year>
    <price>12.99</price>
</book>

<book>
    <title type="fiction">The Lord of the Rings</title>
    <author>J. R. R. Tolkien</author>
    <publisher>George Allen and Unwin</publisher>
    <year>1954</year>
    <price>39.99</price>
</book>

<book>
    <title type="non-fiction">The Right Stuff</title>
    <author>Tom Wolfe</author>
    <publisher>Farra, Staus and Giroux</publisher>
    <year>1979</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
</book>
```

Here is the XSLT:

```
  <xsl:output 
method="html" 
indent="yes" 
version="4.0"
doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"/>

<xsl:template match="/library">
<html>
<body>
    <xsl:for-each select="book">
        <xsl:if test="title[@type='non-fiction']">
            <xsl:if test="price&lt;30" >
                <p class="title"> <xsl:value-of select="title"/></p>
                <p class="author"> <xsl:value-of select="author"/> </p>
                <p class="price"> <xsl:value-of select="price"/> </p>   
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>     
</body>
```

I would like to add the total of the books that are true to all the conditions. I assumed the sum function would do this, but it adds all of the books, regardless if it passed the 'if' statements.

Comment: can you not use the count() function instead of the sum() function?

Comment: I though that count was to add up the amount of items in a list. I'll do some research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to define

- a node-set variable which holds all the books you want to print,
- then loop over that node-set to print the books,
- and at the end use the sum function to calculate the total price.

E.g.

```
<body>
    <xsl:variable name="books" select="book[title[@type='non-fiction']][price&lt;30]" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$books">
        <p class="title"> <xsl:value-of select="title"/></p>
        <p class="author"> <xsl:value-of select="author"/> </p>
        <p class="price"> <xsl:value-of select="price"/> </p>   
    </xsl:for-each>     
    <p class="total-price"> <xsl:value-of select="sum($books/price)"/> </p>   
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer! I found this one to be handier because your explained your reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

You may try this:

```
  <xsl:template match="/library" >
  <html>
  <body>
      <xsl:variable name="fiction_lt30" 
          select="book[title[@type='non-fiction'] and price &lt; 30] " />
      <xsl:for-each select="$fiction_lt30">
        <p class="title"> <xsl:value-of select="title"/></p>
        <p class="author"> <xsl:value-of select="author"/> </p>
        <p class="price"> <xsl:value-of select="price"/> </p>   
      </xsl:for-each>     
        <p>total: <xsl:value-of select="sum($fiction_lt30/price)" /></p>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete and short solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:variable name="vBooks" 
                select="book[title[@type='non-fiction'] and not(price >= 30)]"/>
    <html>
     <body>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="$vBooks"/>
       <p><strong>Total Cost:</strong><span><xsl:value-of 
                                                 select="sum($vBooks/price)"/></span></p>
     </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="book/*[self::title or self::author or self::price]">
   <p class="{name()}"> <xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```